# press button twice to make it work

Tags: android, xml, button, words

I am a beginner in android, and I am making an app related to SpellBee. The problem is I have 2 buttons on screen one for next word and one for previous word. At starting [a default first word shows on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fFoG.jpg) . After pressing next word for the first time it displays next word from the database list. But when i press previous button, on first click it does nothing and on second click it shows the previous word, then on clicking next word button it does nothing and on second click it moves to next word. how can i solve this twice button problem [This is my XML for Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4j3b.jpg)

Code for buttons

```
public void next_click(View view) {
  if(iterator <= wordList.size()) {
    word.setText(wordList.get(iterator));
    definition.setText(definitionList.get(iterator));
    usage.setText(usageList.get(iterator));
    iterator++;
    /*if (iterator == wordList.size()) {
      Toast.makeText(Level1Activity.this, "Level 1 Completed", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      next_word.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Level1Activity.this, 
          SelectLevelActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
       }
     });
    }*/
  }
}

public void previous_click(View view) {
  if(iterator != 0) {
    --iterator;
    word.setText(wordList.get(iterator));
    definition.setText(definitionList.get(iterator));
    usage.setText(usageList.get(iterator));
  }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.msiprestige.spellbee.Level1Activity"
android:background="@drawable/bookshelf"
android:alpha="0.9">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/level_1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/word"
    android:layout_width="261dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textColorLink="#fff"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:text="@string/definition"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.36" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
    android:text="@string/usage"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/definition"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:width="0dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/word" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usage"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:width="0dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/definition" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_word"
    android:layout_width="154dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:onClick="previous_click"
    android:text="Previous Word"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_word"
    android:layout_width="154dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:onClick="next_click"
    android:text="@string/next_word"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post the code of button clicks , also not in the image format .post as text

Comment: can you post you code of Click perform? and Button don't need focusable property in xml

Comment: Post your entire xml layout, it's most likely that the focus is being stolen by the parent view

Comment: i've tried focusable to false. still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you change your code to this one your problem will be solved!
And to know your mistake you were changing the **iterator** variable after setting the word to textview. and in the if for **next_click** it should be less than **wordList.size() - 1** to avoid **IndexOutOfBound** exception!

```
public void next_click(View view) {
  if(iterator < wordList.size()-1) {
    iterator++;
    word.setText(wordList.get(iterator));
    definition.setText(definitionList.get(iterator));
    usage.setText(usageList.get(iterator));
    startAnotherActivity(iterator);
  }
}

public void previous_click(View view) {
  if(iterator != 0) {
    iterator--;
    word.setText(wordList.get(iterator));
    definition.setText(definitionList.get(iterator));
    usage.setText(usageList.get(iterator));
    startAnotherActivity(iterator);
  }
}

private void startAnotherActivity(int your_extra_here) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key_for_extra", your_extra_here);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I felt that you need to pass the iterator to another activity thus I provided an extra for you here. if you don't need it just omit that part!!!

Comment: Yes. That Worked.

Comment: Yes i want to trigger another activity. please do that for me.

Comment: That might work but i want to trigger a new activity only when the iterator reaches to the last word of my wordlist . let's say i have 10 words, when i reach to 10th word on another click it should take me to another activity

Comment: You just need to add a if statement and check when it reaches the end of list size. then in that if statement call startAnotherActivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is logical mistake. As your list **index starts with 0**, when you show first word, i guess **iterator index has become 1**. Now, when you click next, you **showed word at index 1** and incremented iterator. now **iterator is 2**.

Now, Click on the previous button. here first iterator is decremented i.e **iterator is 1**. and showing the **word at index 1** which is already displaying on the screen. so you feel it does nothing but it actually executes your logic. Its just that your logic is setting the same word. Now again click on previous button, **iterator will be 0** and it shows word at index 0.

same case with next button. now, click on next button. you are setting word first i.e **showing word at index 0** which is being displayed already and increments **iterator which will become 1**. now click again on next button, it shows **word at index 1** and increments **iterator to 2**.

**Make sure your counter i.e iterator always points to the current word index that is being displayed currently. When click on next, see iterator+1 is with in the range of word list, if so then increment it and show the word at that index. similarly, while showing previous word, check if index-1 is within the range of word list, if so then decrement it and then show the word at that index**. Hope you understand.